# Cannot get Scala to run

Tags: scala, installation, classnotfoundexception

I've tried on two separate occasions to get Scala installed on my MacBook Air and have run into the same problem both times.

The first stime I installed scala, I moved all the appropriate files into the bin, lib, & src directories. When I type "scala" in the Terminal I get the following error:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java/lang/ClassNotFoundException: error in opening JAR file /usr/lib/charset.alias
```

So I have poked around and tried to figure it out. The problem I'm running into is this seems to be a fairly common error (and I understand what causes this error) but I can't figure out what is actually causing this to happen. I made sure I had all the proper .jar files in my lib directory. After a while, I decided to try installing Scala using Homebrew. After successfully installing Scala using Homebrew, I get the same error above when I type "scala" in the Terminal.

What am I missing? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure you have a valid `$SCALA_HOME`?

Comment: @om-nom-nom No, I am not sure I have a valid $SCALA_HOME. How can I check this?

Comment: I've actually looked [inside](http://hastebin.com/luxuvayido.coffee) `scala` script (near the 50th line) and it looks like it doesn't matter.

Comment: Can you run the scala *compiler*? That is, running scalac on a trivial program works?

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral - just tried to compile a sample HelloWorld program and got the exact same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing via [HomeBrew](https://brew.sh). You can get SBT that way, too,

Edit:

D'Oh! You did... In which case, I'd look into whether you Java / JVM / JRE / JDK installation is intact. The name of the file it's complaining about is suspect for a Mac.

Edit the next:

I really shouldn't shoot from the hip so much. My MacBook *does* have that file! It contains this:

```
# This file contains a table of character encoding aliases,
# suitable for operating system 'darwin10.0'.
# It was automatically generated from config.charset.
# Packages using this file:  
* UTF-8
```

Comment: that's exactly what my charset.alias file contains as well. Any recommendation on testing whether my Java/JVM/JRE/JDE installation is intact? I'm planning on just trying to compile and run a simple program but want to make sure I'm not missing something. Thanks!

Comment: I successfully compiled and ran a Java program so everything seems to be working fine there. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @galois: I can't think of anything. You could get another data point by trying to create an SBT project and see if it will run Scala sucessfully.